# Munit integration test cases fail when I create multiple suites but works when I add all the test cases in a single file

Tags: timeout, integration-testing, github-actions, mule4, munit

I am trying to write integration test cases(without mocking responses) for my mule flows using Munit. I have created 2 different test suites for 2 of the flows under test. Individually these tests run successfully in my local. But the build fails in my CI/CD pipeline when running them altogether.

**If I add all these test cases in a single file it works successfully**. Wondering if there is any fix for this as I do not want to clutter all my test cases in a single file.
Below are specific details:
**Munit version: 2.3.0**

**Mule 4**

**CICD platform: Github actions**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml plugins related to MUnits and Deployment.

Comment: I use munit tools(2.3.7) and munit runner(2.3.7). I use the below command to run my test files using tags: mvn -e -s mvn-settings.xml clean verify -Dmunit.tags=integrationTest

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: I get this error for the failed test cases: org.mule.munit.common.exception.MunitError: The test 'sometest_flowname' timeout after 120000 milliseconds. But this only happens if I split it into separate files. If I keep all the test cases in a single file it works fine.

Comment: Exact version of Mule? Please share examples of test cases that can be used to reproduce the issue. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Version: Mule 4.4.0

Comment: Please provide examples.

Comment: I understand the challenges of not having an example to debug from. Unfortunately, I am using a 3rd party service and hence will not be able to give the exact scenario here. I have tried reproducing the issue using basic web service consumer. But the issue is not reproducible there.